# view layout rebol 3 not working

Tags: windows, rebol, rebol3

I've copied Rebol3 to my computer under windows.  I am running it from the download not a full install, and it and seemed ok.

I tried using some very simple sample code for the GUI in the console and it fails with various error messages.

If I put in `view [` and type enter it tells me its a syntax error (this works in reb/view 2).

Its a win 7 machine.

Version of Rebol3 is *2014-03-04 04:54*

When I used `help` and typed the command `what`, `view` wasn't listed as a command.

Comment: The version of Rebol is obtained using rebol/version for any version of rebol.

Answer (score 3):

Note the runtime support for the Rebol3 GUI dialect is not available in the "core" builds available at http://rebolsource.net.

Currently the GUI dialect is available in Linux/Android and Windows builds from Atronix Engineering:

http://atronixengineering.com/downloads.html

Or from Saphirion AG:

http://development.saphirion.com/rebol/saphir/

Note that the GUI behaviors in Rebol3 are similar to Rebol2's VID but has some differences, and is called R3-GUI.  For a tutorial you might try [Cross Platform App Development with Rebol 3 Saphir](http://learnrebol.com/rebol3_book.html)

Also notice that before invoking VIEW you will have to LOAD-GUI.

> If I put in view [ and type enter it tells me its a syntax error (this works in reb/view 2).

The Rebol3 console is more basic than the Rebol2 console, and unfortunately doesn't support multi-line input at this time.  You can only enter complete expressions before hitting enter, not partial ones.  So hitting enter while there is still an unclosed bracket will give you an error.  However if the code you're putting in is coming from the clipboard you can use **do clipboard://** *([via @GrahamChiu](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15712154#15712154))*

While Rebol3 currently lacks the behavior, it's encouraging that the [Red console](http://www.red-lang.org/p/contributions.html) handles multi-line input in the Rebol2 way.

> I am running it from the download not a full install

And the good thing is that you can run it from the download with no install.  Because there is no install.  :-)

Comment: Does anyone know if the Rebol SDK/Encap work with Rebol 3? A quick search turns up this, which I've never heard of: http://r3al.org/rebol3-encapper.html

Comment: @Edoc I haven't seen that either.  But if you want to address the room in terms of "does anyone know?" on StackOverflow, [stop by the chat](http://rebolsource.net/go/chat-faq) *(as only I will be notified about this comment on my posting)*!